# SQL Distributed Reporting Services Setup

Tags: sql-server, installation, ssrs

I am setting up two servers; one iis 7 and one sql 2008.  I need to use reporting services.  What is the best way to set up reporting services so that my iis box can serve the reports.  I'm sure this is not an unusual configuration, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding an answer to this - probably because I am using the wrong terminology.  Also does this configuration require two sql licenses (one for each server)?

This sound like a lengthy explanation so links or even the correct terminology for this so I can find the answers myself would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a fantastic article](http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2008/06/05/reporting-services-scale-out-architecture.aspx) that explains the architecture you are looking for, as well as containing links for instructions to set it up.

Also, yes, that configuration will require two SQL Server licenses, one for the reporting server, and one for the database server.